# Proguard warns about deleted classes

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I am using proguard to obfuscate my code in Android Studio.
I have deleted many classes from my project and do not use them but proguard warns me about those deleted classes. If i don't use proguard, the app compiles fine.

I tried `Invalidate Caches/Restart` option but made no difference.

Here are the warnings :

```
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$1: can't find superclass or interface com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$2: can't find superclass or interface com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$3: can't find superclass or interface com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$4: can't find superclass or interface com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$5: can't find superclass or interface com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$6: can't find superclass or interface com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$7: can't find superclass or interface com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$1: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$1: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.SampleApp
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.SampleApp
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$AddFaceTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$DetectionTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.SampleApp
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$DetectionTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$DetectionTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$DetectionTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$DetectionTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$DetectionTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$DetectionTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.SampleApp
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$DetectionTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$DetectionTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$DetectionTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$DetectionTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$DetectionTask: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter$1: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter$1: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter$1: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter$1: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter$1: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter$1: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.AddFaceToPersonActivity$FaceGridViewAdapter
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.reflect.Type getType()' in program class com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$1
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.reflect.Type getType()' in program class com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$2
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.reflect.Type getType()' in program class com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$3
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.reflect.Type getType()' in program class com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$4
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.reflect.Type getType()' in program class com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$5
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.reflect.Type getType()' in program class com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$6
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient: can't find referenced method 'java.lang.reflect.Type getType()' in program class com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$7
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$1: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$1: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$1: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$2: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$2: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$2: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$3: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$3: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$3: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$4: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$4: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$4: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$5: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$5: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$5: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$6: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$6: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$6: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$7: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$7: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.FaceServiceClient$7: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.WebServiceRequest: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.WebServiceRequest: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.WebServiceRequest: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.ServiceCallException
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.WebServiceRequest: can't find referenced class com.google.gson.Gson
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.WebServiceRequest: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.ServiceCallException
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.WebServiceRequest: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.ServiceCallException
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.WebServiceRequest: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.ServiceCallException
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.WebServiceRequest: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.ServiceCallException
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.WebServiceRequest: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.ServiceCallException
Warning: com.mypack.myapp.WebServiceRequest: can't find referenced class com.mypack.myapp.ServiceCallException
```

Here is the `proguard` related part in `build.gradle` :

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

Here is `proguard-rules.pro` file :

```
-verbose

-dontwarn android.support.**

-keep class -verbose

-dontwarn android.support.**

-keep class -verbose

-dontwarn android.support.**

-keep class com.mypack.myapp.R { 
*;
}

#below commands for including the line numbers in traces
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile    
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable.R { 
*;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, the problem is solved by simply deleting the entire `build` folder.